# HTTPS calls in react native expo project is throwing Network error

Tags: react-native, https, expo

I tried with the below mentioned in **app.json**:

```
"infoPlist": {
    "NSAppTransportSecurity" : {
      "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" : true,
      "NSExceptionDomains": {
        "****MYSERVERURL****":{
          "NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads": true,
          "NSIncludesSubdomains": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but still I am getting same error, I referred few example and did so, even the same URL is not getting open in *safari* browser also.

Answer (score -1):

try With this --- worked for me in Xcode

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Also one more option, if you want to disable ATS you can use this :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
 <dict>  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
 </dict>
```

But this is not recommended at all. The server should have the SSL certificates and so that there is no privacy leaks.

Comment: need solution specific to EXPO, or how can I do this through EXPO, I tried this by writing in app.json, but it didn't worked.